# how to handle mysql update error using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am  having some issue that is facing me with running the following dismiss functions,

So page with an alert bootstrap that I have named as notifications-success.php goes as follows:

```
<?php 
$root = realpath(str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ); 
include ($root . '/insights/ss/onix.php'); 

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from notifications where seen = 0");
    if ($result)
    {      
    if($result->num_rows) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {?> 
    
<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert' style='margin-left:-12px;'>
 <button type="button" class="close" onClick="updateId('<?php echo $row['id'];?>')" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" style="float:left!important; border:0; background:none;"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

<strong><span class="text-success" style="margin-top:-50px;"><i class='fa fa-check'></i> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; File has been moved successfully</strong><br>To confirm reading this message please press x button </span></div>

<?php       }
    }
   
}
                  ?>
                  
                  <script>
function updateId(id)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "dismisssuccess.php?id=" +id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Action file which is dismisssuccess.php goes as follows:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$root = realpath(str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ); 
include ($root . '/insights/ss/onix.php'); 

    $update = "UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 , seenby = '$ip' WHERE id = '".$id."'";

    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $update))
    {
              echo "success";   
 
            

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "There is some error";
    }
    die;
}
?>
```

Now when I press x , the update statement doesn't actually run, meanwhile, when i open dismisssuccess file by http with relevant id it works fine with no error and does the update required, also works fine only when I change the table to be update.

Does anyone have clue what could be possible reason behind this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that your `UPDATE` query is widely open for SQL injection

Comment: Your generated HTML markup is incorrectly nested .. one portion begins `<strong><span<` but ends `</strong><br>To confirm reading this message please press x button </span>`

Comment: Also - you ajax function does nothing with any returned content so why bother generating any in php?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @NicoHaase what i have tried are 1. running action file using http and target id and update stmt have worked only seperately from notification file 2. changing target table to be updated also have made my code to be fully working

Comment: my database is protected by another service so my aim is not to work on securing sql injection as this is already handled by another service, and so I only write down simply in that way as in above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak the PHP & HTML so that the nesting is correct and assign a new dataset attribute to the button rather than the inline event handler.

```
<?php

    $root = realpath(str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ); 
    include ($root . '/insights/ss/onix.php'); 

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from notifications where seen = 0");
        if ($result){
            if($result->num_rows) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?> 
    
<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert' style='margin-left:-12px;'>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-id="<?=$row['id'];?>" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" style="float:left!important; border:0; background:none;">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

    <strong>
        <span class="text-success" style="margin-top:-50px;">
            <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;File has been moved successfully
        </span>
    </strong>
    <br>
    To confirm reading this message please press X button 
</div>

<?php
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

Use an externally registered event handler and why not use the `fetch` api ~ appears slightly shorter and is a better api moving forwards.

```
<script>
    function updateId(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        let id=e.target!=e.currentTarget ? e.target.parentNode.dataset.id : e.target.dataset.id;
        fetch( 'dismisssuccess.php?id='+id )
            .then(r=>r.text())
            .then(text=>console.log(text))
    }
    document.querySelectorAll('div[role="alert"] button[data-id]').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',updateId))
</script>
```

Within the PHP you really, really should use a `prepared statement` when dealing with user supplied data - otherwise all your hard work could be undone by one malicious user!

```
<?php 

    if( !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ){

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        
        $root = realpath(str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) );
        include ($root . '/insights/ss/onix.php'); 

        $sql='UPDATE `notifications` SET `seen`=1, `seenby`=? where `id`=?';
        
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$ip,$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        exit( $rows ? 'Success' : 'There is some error' );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Same thing, unexpectedly not updating thru the notifications dot php file

Comment: do you see any errors in the developer console? Can you confirm that the AJAX request is reaching the designated endpoint and also that it is sending the ID as expected?!

Comment: OK - just ran a little test and it is the `span` element within the `button` that mainly propagates the event so a little tweak to the Javascript function is required. My fault -sorry dude.

Comment: yea it is now working after truncating the span tag! thank u for saving me that time